# Trouble filtering DNS responses with tcpdump

Tags: domain-name-system, tcpdump

I'm having troubles with tcpdump. I want to only capture DNS packets that are responses containing authoritative responses with a single RR that is 0.0.0.0. For example I want to only capture packets like this:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# tcpdump -XKvvv 'udp src port 53'
tcpdump: listening on br-lan, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:40:19.929483 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60020, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 74)
    OpenWrt.lan.53 > 192.168.0.231.12244: 730* q: A? test.2o7.net. 1/0/0 test.2o7.net. [0s] A 0.0.0.0 (46)
        0x0000:  4500 004a ea74 4000 4011 cdf5 c0a8 0001  E..J.t@.@.......
        0x0010:  c0a8 00e7 0035 2fd4 0036 8280 02da 8580  .....5/..6......
        0x0020:  0001 0001 0000 0000 0474 6573 7403 326f  .........test.2o
        0x0030:  3703 6e65 7400 0001 0001 c00c 0001 0001  7.net...........
        0x0040:  0000 0000 0004 0000 0000                 ..........
^C
1 packet captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

The UDP header is always 8 bytes so the start of the UDP data should be at udp[7] in the filter syntax. The DNS packet starts with 2 bytes of ID then a two byte flag word so the flag word should start at offset 9, and the AA bit is bit 5 of flag. But when I test that out with filter `udp port 53 and (udp[9:2]&0xfbff) != 0` it doesn't print only authoritative answers. This is what happens:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# tcpdump -XKvvv 'udp src port 53 and (udp[9:2]&0xfbff) != 0'
tcpdump: listening on br-lan, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:42:42.233028 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16920, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    OpenWrt.lan.53 > 192.168.0.231.50259: 55688 q: A? duckduckgo.com. 1/0/0 duckduckgo.com. [1m26s] A 52.250.42.157 (48)
        0x0000:  4500 004c 4218 4000 4011 7650 c0a8 0001  E..LB.@.@.vP....
        0x0010:  c0a8 00e7 0035 c453 0038 8282 d988 8180  .....5.S.8......
        0x0020:  0001 0001 0000 0000 0a64 7563 6b64 7563  .........duckduc
        0x0030:  6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001 c00c 0001  kgo.com.........
        0x0040:  0001 0000 0056 0004 34fa 2a9d            .....V..4.*.
^C
1 packet captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

But that's not an AA. What is wrong?

Comment: I don't know much about tcpdump or DNS, but normally if you want to skip 10 bytes, the offset you should use is `10` (which means to *inclusively* start from "byte 10" a.k.a. the eleventh byte).

Comment: @TomYan I tried that as well no luck.

Comment: The bitmask is wrong too. You should use `(udp[10:2]&0x400) != 0` (or even better, `(udp[10:1]&0x4) != 0`).

Comment: @TomYan Wow I'm an idiot! That worked to filter by AA now I guess I just have to do the rest which should be pretty easy. I can't believe I messed up with the bitmask.

Comment: What if i want to sort packts with AA and RA is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `udp src port 53 and (udp[10:2]&0x840f) = 0x8400 and udp[14:2] = 1` now and that works. It only lists DNS responses with QR set to 1 (response), AA set to 1 (authoritative), rCode set to 0 (no error), and authority RR set to 1 (one authority RR). I also wanted to filter based on the RR itself but its offset is variable and I don't think the pcap filter syntax is powerful enough to do that (but I might be wrong). So this is enough for me.

Comment: What if i want to sort packts with AA and RA is  1